# How to set/pass value from a custom cell to a viewcontroller in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift, uiswitch

In my program, there is a UISwitch in the custom UITableCell of a UITableView under a view controller.
I create a variable in the view controller and try to record the amount of all UISwitch.on.

How do I set value in the view controller from the UISwitch Action ?

I wrote these code in UISwitch Action. count is the variable in the ViewController

```
        var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as ViewController            
        rootViewController.count++
        println("count:\(rootViewController.count)")
```

It works in my sample program, but it has error when I wrote in my formal program.
It always shows "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)".

Do I have another way to record the amount of UISwitch.on ??

### How do I set/pass value to viewcontroller from table cell ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using delegate you can do these .

- when switch is ON call delegate that is present in view controller.
- In delegate method increment count variable.

Comment: But my switch is in a UITableViewCell. I have no idea how to call delegate of viewcontroller from the UITableViewCell. I put a switch in a custom table cell. The cell is belong to a Table, and that table is in a View. The delegate is implemented in the view controller. The custom cell has its own class. I don't know how to call any function of the view controller.

Comment: It is simple, declare delegate in custom cell and define it in view controller. In each cell assign cell.delegate = self. If switch state change call delegate function form custom cell to view controller